# PowerShell formating numbers by variables

Tags: powershell, format

I have integer values: 3 60 150 1500 and float values 1.23354, 1.234, 1.234567...
I calculate the number of digits of the biggest integer:

```
    $nInt = [System.Math]::Ceiling([math]::log10($maxInt))
    # nInt = 4
```

and in another way the biggest number of dec. behind the decimal point of the float-variable: $nDec = 6

1. How can I format a print out that all integer do have the same string-length with leading spaces?

   ```
   |1500
   | 500
   |  60
   |   3
   ```
2. And all float with the same string-length as well?

   ```
      1.234567|
      1.23354 |
      1.234   |
   ```

The `|` is just to mark my 'point of measure'.

Of course I have to choose a character-set where all characters do have the same pixex-size.

I am thinking of formatting by "{0:n}" or $int.ToString(""), but I can't see how to use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try PadLeft or PadRight. For example, for your integers:

```
$maxInt.ToString().PadLeft($nInt.ToString().Length, ' ')
```